# Ekko-Lightbox stop working after converting HTML template into wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I would like to educated what i might be doing wrong here. I'm converting HTML template to Wordpress. So far everything else is working except the EKKO-lightbox.
I have enqueued my css & js to the light box folder in functions.php (I assume it should automatically start working on the page as other elements did) but the light box wont just work/pop open the images.
Did I miss something?

My lightboxpage.php and functions.php snap is attached
[Function and page snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGD8g.jpg)

functions.php

Comment: First of all, [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1427878), second - [ask].

Comment: Start by checking if the JS & CSS resources could actually be loaded, or whether you might have gotten 404s for those or something.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe . Your advice was help. I finally figured it out. The problem was my $handle name 'jquery' in functions.php. I just renamed it and it started to work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Took 3days (still learning) but i figured it out. I guess the $handle 'jquery' is reserved in WordPress. I also wp_enqueue_script and wp_enqueue_style of the Ekko-lightbox

I updated it to :

function load_stylesheets()
{

```
wp_register_style('ekkolightbox', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/ekko-lightbox.css', array(''), 1, 'all' );
wp_enqueue_style('ekkolightbox');
```

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_stylesheets');

function addjs()
{

```
wp_register_script('customscripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js', array('jquery') , 1, 1, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script('customscripts');

wp_register_script('ekkomin', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/ekko-lightboxmin.js', array() , 1, 1, 1 );
wp_enqueue_script('ekkomin');
```

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addjs');

Thank you all.